# Shuffle range with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, range, shuffle

I am studying Java `ArrayList`, and I want to fill an `ArrayList` of 20 `Integer`(s) with random numbers from `0` to `10`. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class manejoListas {
    ArrayList<Integer> lista=new ArrayList<>(20);

    public void llenarLista() {
        for (int i=0; i<20;i++) {
                lista.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(lista);
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

and this is the output:

> [3, 5, 9, 10, 19, 8, 6, 4, 15, 2, 0, 18, 16, 12, 14, 7, 17, 13, 1, 11]

How can I get the range from 0 - 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change

```
lista.add(i);
```

to

```
lista.add(i / 2);
```

which will reduce the range to `0` (inclusive) - `10` (exclusive). Note that every number will appear twice. If you want the values to be more randomly distributed, you could use [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) like

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public void llenarLista() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        lista.add(rand.nextInt(10));
    }
    // Collections.shuffle(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);
}
```

Comment: Guess, can remove that shuffle completely. OP confused with Shuffle and Random

Comment: That was very helpful, i´m gonna have a test next week and i´m  practicing everything i can. Tank you very much! :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You can do it with `shuffle`, see the first part of my answer. But it means, among other things, that the last element is perfectly predictable.

Answer (score 2):

> Java and i want to fill an ArrayList of 20 elements with random numbers from 0 to 10

In that case you need Random numbers. Not shuffle function.

```
Random rn = new Random();
```

And then

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        lista.add(rn.nextInt(10););
    }
```

That keeps adding random numbers between 0 and 10.